# opencv_contrib unable to compile program (even though build was successful) with OpenCV 3.0.0 beta

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I installed the latest version of opencv (OpenCv 3.0.0 Beta). I downloaded the opencv_contrib module and built it with opencv by doing a cmake (by following the instructions in the readme https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib). The build happened successfully. I wrote a simple program which uses creates a BasicFaceRecognizer model. However, when I compile my program I get the following error message
fatal error: opencv2/face.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include"opencv2/face.hpp"
The code is very simple. Just wanted to check if it compiles before proceeding further.

```
#include"opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
#include"opencv2/face.hpp"
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::face;
int main()
{
    Ptr<BasicFaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, OpenCV 3.0.0 Beta is not the latest release (2014-11-11). Last release is OpenCV 3.0.0 (2015-06-04).  Post the code you're using..

Comment: Works for me, you have probably messed up with includes and libraries